# Stream video through php server

Tags: php, video, stream

I have a video on my server and i want stream it through html 5 video player with php. I have found a class for this (https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293), but it doesn't work for large files. What can i do to show properly video?

```
class VideoStream
{
private $path = "";
private $stream = "";
private $buffer = 102400;
private $start  = -1;
private $end    = -1;
private $size   = 0;

function __construct($filePath) 
{
    $this->path = $filePath;
}

/**
 * Open stream
 */
private function open()
{
    if (!($this->stream = fopen($this->path, 'rb'))) {
        die('Could not open stream for reading');
    }

}

/**
 * Set proper header to serve the video content
 */
private function setHeader()
{
    ob_get_clean();
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
    header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
    $this->start = 0;
    $this->size  = filesize($this->path);
    $this->end   = $this->size - 1;
    header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

        $c_start = $this->start;
        $c_end = $this->end;

        list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
            exit;
        }
        if ($range == '-') {
            $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
        }else{
            $range = explode('-', $range);
            $c_start = $range[0];

            $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
        }
        $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
        if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= $this->size) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
            exit;
        }
        $this->start = $c_start;
        $this->end = $c_end;
        $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
        fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header("Content-Length: ".$length);
        header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this->size);
    }
    else
    {
        header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
    }  

}

/**
 * close curretly opened stream
 */
private function end()
{
    fclose($this->stream);
    exit;
}

/**
 * perform the streaming of calculated range
 */
private function stream()
{
    $i = $this->start;
    set_time_limit(0);
    while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end) {
        $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
        if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
        }
        $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
        echo $data;
        flush();
        $i += $bytesToRead;
    }
}

/**
 * Start streaming video content
 */
function start()
{
    $this->open();
    $this->setHeader();
    $this->stream();
    $this->end();
}
```

}

Comment: Just get a streaming bundle specifically designed for streaming,php wont cut it.Like this one http://serviio.org/

Comment: There is no way php could supply video to html5?

Comment: It's not working for secure server(https)